Есть почтовый сервер с множеством папок спам нужне башскрипт для удаления всех файлов в большом количестве папок в определенное время в 12 ночи каждый
Есть почтовый сервер с множеством папок спам нужне башскрипт для удаления всех файлов в большом количестве папок в определенное время в 12 ночи каждый день на debiane

rm -r /"Множество папок"  разве не так?

Отройте для себя понятия  crontab и/или logrotate
